# Can I use my local dependencies with Dataflow for Python SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

Dataflow for Python SDK have a `--requirements_file option`, that can take a standard [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files), and install it on its workers before running. Are there any restriction in using these files? Specifically can I use all pip flags (e.g. `--editable_mode` or `-e`) to install my local packages?

Answer (score 2):

Dataflow for Python SDK will run `pip install -r requirements.txt` before starting your workload. It is important that all the items reference in the requirements file are accessible to the worker machines. Dependencies on PyPI, or some other accessible location (e.g. http) will install correctly, local packages (e.g. `-e my_package`) will not because they will not be accessible by workers.

`--extra_package` option would allow staging local packages in an accessible way. Instead of listing local packages in the `requirements.txt`, create a tarball of the local package (e.g. `my_package.tar.gz`) and use `--extra_package` option to stage them.

[Managing Python Pipeline Dependencies](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/) have more details on these options.

Comment: What should be in the tarball, exactly? The folder that I passed to pip install -e ? Should setup.py be at the root of the tarball?

Comment: tarball is the source distribution. You can use `python setup.py sdist` to create one. (More info: https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html)